Dual problem of a convex problem from discrete mixing distribution
I'm studying the paper [1] and trying to understand the primal-dual problems introduced in the middle of page 4 of [1]. Below is the problem in question:

Let $A$ be a fixed $n \times m$ matrix, where each element is positive.
Consider the following primal problem:
\begin{align*}
\min \quad  & -\sum_{i=1}^n \log(g_i) \\
\mathrm{subject~to} \quad & Af = g, \\
& 1_m^\top f = 1, \\
& f \succeq 0,
\end{align*}
where $\succeq$ denotes elementwise inequality.
The authors claim that the corresponding dual problem becomes
\begin{align*}
\max_{\nu \in \mathbb R^n} \quad  & \sum_{i=1}^n \log(\nu_i) \\
\mathrm{subject~to} \quad & A^\top \nu \preceq n 1_m, \\
& \nu \succeq 0.
\end{align*}
Unfortunately, I cannot derive the primal to dual. Could anyone provide ideas or hints for converting this primal problem to its dual form? Thank you for any hints or suggestions.

[1] Koenker, R., & Gu, J. (2017). REBayes: An R Package for Empirical Bayes Mixture Methods. Journal of Statistical Software, 82(8), 1–26. https://doi.org/10.18637/jss.v082.i08
